# How to show value of 'i' (for loop) inside FileReader.onload

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, filereader

I am trying to show preview of multiple image files through `input file` and assign each of them a specific id (`i` generated from for loop). Everything is working fine, but there is problem in assigning them id.

My code is:

```
function fileSelected() {
var files = event.target.files;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    

   var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) { 
  var picWrap = '<img id="'+i+'" src="'+event.target.result'" />';
}
reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
} }
```

I'm using `onclick` for using this function

Now according to the above code I am getting the preview of all files, but there is problem with their ID.

Like if I select 2 files then result is

```
(filePreview) Id = 2
 (filePreview2) Id = 2
```

and if I select 3 files then I get the preview of all 3 files but their ID becomes 3 for each pic, and if I select single file then then I value becomes 1 and not 0.

Comment: You should use onChange in file input field.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the `onload` event happens the loop has already finished, with the loop index being the last value.
One option would be to do the following, which sets i in the callback to the value supplied when calling bind:

```
reader.onload = (function(i, event) { 
  var picWrap = '<img id="'+i+'" src="'+event.target.result'" />';
}).bind(reader, i);
```